# AJAX-PHP Stay on same page if validation fails

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a validation check with ajax and it will show errors. However, it will show the error and then immediately go to the form send page displaying the errors.

The page is incredibly long - so I'll paste an example of what I have for the ajax section.

I should note that everything here programmatically works as intended - the **only** problem is that it will display the error via ajax (as it should) then redirects to submit_form.php after a couple of seconds with the error message displayed in plain text.

**HTML**

```
<form action="submit_form.php" method="post" id="form_1">
   <input type="text" name="text_box" class="form-control" id="text_box" placeholder="Enter Text Here">
   <button type="submit" name="submit_form" id="submit_form" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
        $('#submit_form).on('click', function () {
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "submit_form.php",
               dataType: "json",
               data: $('#form_1').serialize(),
               success: function (json) {
             $('.message_center').html('');
                   if(json['success']) {
               $('.message_center').html('<div class="row">'+
                                        '   <div class="col-md-12">'+
                                        '     <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">'+
                                        '       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>'+
                                        '       <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i> Success!</h4>'+
                                        '       '+json['success']+''+
                                        '     </div>'+
                                        '   </div>'+
                                        ' </div> ');
             }
             if(json['error']) {
               var html='';
               $.each( json['error'], function( key, value ) {
                html += value+'<br>';
              });
              $('.message_center').html('<div class="row">'+
                                              '   <div class="col-md-12">'+
                                              '     <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible">'+
                                              '       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>'+
                                              '       <h4><i class="icon fa fa-warning"></i> Error! There was a problem.</h4>'+
                                              '       '+html+''+
                                              '     </div>'+
                                              '   </div>'+
                                              ' </div> ');
             }

               }

           });
       });
    </script>
```

**SUBMIT_FORM.PHP**

```
<?php session_start();

$json = array(); 

if ($_POST['text_box'] === NULL) {
  $json['error'][] = "Please enter data in textbox.";
} else {
  $textData = $_POST['text_box'];
}

if($json){ // If any Errors, return else, insert data into database.

    echo json_encode($json);
    exit;

} else {

    // insert query that works is here.


echo json_encode($json);
exit;

} 


?>
```

Comment: I think you need to remove the `action="submit_form.php"` in your `form` tag and let ajax do the work in submitting your form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the default action of `form` i.e. `submit` when `input type` of `submit` is clicked, so that your `ajax` process runs smoothly. In your `click` event add `e.preventDefault();`

```
$('#submit_form').on('click', function (e) {
     //get the e as parameter
     e.preventDefault();
     //rest of your code.
});
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Worked perfectly.

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using addEventListener, then call event.preventDefault() to stop the form from submitting if there is an error, like this:

```
$('#submit_form').addEventListener('click', function (event) {

// Prevents form from submitting
             event.preventDefault();

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "submit_form.php",
       dataType: "json",
       data: $('#form_1').serialize(),
       success: function (json) {
        $('.message_center').html('');

        if(json['success']) {

         $('.message_center')
          .html('<div class="row">'+
            '   <div class="col-md-12">'+
            '     <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">'+
            '       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>'+
            '       <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i> Success!</h4>'+
            '       '+json['success']+''+
            '     </div>'+
            '   </div>'+
            ' </div> ');
       }

       if(json['error']) {

         var html='';
         $.each( json['error'], function( key, value ) {
          html += value+'<br>';
        });
        $('.message_center')
          .html('<div class="row">'+
            '   <div class="col-md-12">'+
            '     <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible">'+
            '       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>'+
            '       <h4><i class="icon fa fa-warning"></i> Error! There was a problem.</h4>'+
            '       '+html+''+
            '     </div>'+
            '   </div>'+
            ' </div> ');
       }

    }

   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Worked perfectly.