# How to display the html div so that after form submit the error messgae is displayed automatically

Tags: html, css

I have a form that validates whether the username and password is correct or not but it does not show the error messages unless i click on the form again.The form is inside a html div tag, I want to know how to style the div with css so that the error messages can be displayed automatically after form submit. Here is my code

```
<h3 class="registration-header">
Log in. </h3>
<div class="registration-box-info"><span>
Please enter username and password  </span></div>
<form action="/" charset="UTF-8" method="post">
            <div class="error-message alert-danger">
        <span>Sorry, unrecognized username or password.<a href="#">Have you forgotten your password?</a></span>
    </div>
```

The error message is not displayed automatically after inserting wrong input and so I would be grateful if you can tell me how to style the div using css to make it visible after submitting wrong input

Comment: you need to learn a bit of js to make your validation show - or use html 5 error attributes

Comment: you can use jquery validation https://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: vist https://css-tricks.com/form-validation-ux-html-css/ for getting basics of forms and validations with demo

Comment: The validation are working fine but the error message is not visible automatically.The error messga e can only be seen after clicking the register button again.I wanted to know is there anything I can do with the div styling so that the content (error message)inside the div is visible after form submit.

Comment: The validation is working fine.I only want to show div class="error-message alert-danger">
        <span>Sorry, unrecognized username or password.<a href="#">Have you forgotten your password?</a></span>
    </div> automatically after submitting wrong username and password

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without js, you could use

```
:valid 
:invalid
```

CSS pseudo class and style the border of the input accordingly.

You could also attach a pattern to the validation.

Check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: Thanks Gregor.I already have the validation but want to show the error messages automatically after submitting the form if the username and password is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

For checking wheather username and other filed are empty or not, you have to just add `required` inside the tag like `<input type="text" name="full-name" id="full-name" placeholder="Name" required />` An for validation visit https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-family: 'helvetica neue', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  color: #222;
}

#form {
  max-width: 700px;
  padding: 2rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-field {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
}
label, input {
  width: 70%;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}
label {
  text-align: right;
  width: 30%;
}
input {
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
.error-message {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    margin-left: 30%;
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="/" id="form" class="validate">
  <div class="form-field">
    <label for="full-name">Full Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="full-name" id="full-name" placeholder="Name" required />
  </div>
  <div class="form-field">
    <label for="email-input">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email-input" id="email-input" placeholder="test@gmail.com" required />
  </div>
  <div class="form-field">
    <label for="password-input">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password-input" id="password-input" required />
  </div>
  <div class="form-field">
    <label for=""></label>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much but I wanted to share that The validation are working fine but the error message is not visible automatically.The error messga e can only be seen after clicking the register button again.I wanted to know is there anything I can do with the div styling so that the content (error message)inside the div is visible after form submit

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jquery, and if you want customise your kind of error,

like, if you enter, 'map', derive' or 'glossary, you have different message.
If you enter '???' or anything else you'll have your message 'Sorry, unrecognized...'

You can use :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  #div1   {background-color: red;}
  #div2   {background-color: blue;}
  #div3   {background-color: black;
    color: white;}
  #error   {background-color: red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3 class="registration-header">
Log in. </h3>
<div class="registration-box-info"><span>
Please enter username and password  </span></div>
<!-- form action="/" charset="UTF-8" method="post" -->
<input type="text" placeholder="ENTER COMMAND" />

<div id="div1">div1 : you entered the log 'map'</div>
<div id="div2">div2 : you entered the log 'derive'</div>
<div id="div3">div1= : you entered the log 'glossary'</div>
<div id="error"><span>Sorry, unrecognized username or password.<a href="#">Have you forgotten your password?</a></span></div>
 

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Hide both <div> by default
  $('#div1').hide();
  $('#div2').hide();
  $('#div3').hide();
  $('#error').hide();

  // Check on keydown
  $('input').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $('#div1').hide();
      $('#div2').hide();
      $('#div3').hide();
      $('#error').hide();
      if (value == 'map') { // If input value is div1
        $('#div1').slideDown();
      } else if (value == 'derive') { // If input value is div2
        $('#div2').slideDown();
      } else if (value == 'glossary') { // If input value is div3
        $('#div3').slideDown();
      } else if (value != '') { // If input value is wrong
        //$('#error').html(value + " is an incorrect input value");
        $('#error').slideDown();
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  #div1   {background-color: red;}
  #div2   {background-color: blue;}
  #div3   {background-color: black;
    color: white;}
  #error   {background-color: red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3 class="registration-header">
Log in. </h3>
<div class="registration-box-info"><span>
Please enter username and password  </span></div>
<form  action="submit_form.php" method="post" id="form_1" charset="UTF-8" >
<input id="submit_form" type="text" placeholder="ENTER COMMAND" />
</form>

<div id="div1">div1 : you entered the log 'map'</div>
<div id="div2">div2 : you entered the log 'derive'</div>
<div id="div3">div1= : you entered the log 'glossary'</div>
<div id="error"><span>Sorry, unrecognized username or password.<a href="#">Have you forgotten your password?</a></span></div>
 

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Hide both <div> by default
  $('#div1').hide();
  $('#div2').hide();
  $('#div3').hide();
  $('#error').hide();

  // Check on keydown
  $('input').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $('#div1').hide();
      $('#div2').hide();
      $('#div3').hide();
      $('#error').hide();
      if (value == 'map') { // If input value is div1
        $('#div1').slideDown();
      } else if (value == 'derive') { // If input value is div2
        $('#div2').slideDown();
      } else if (value == 'glossary') { // If input value is div3
        $('#div3').slideDown();
      } else if (value != '') { // If input value is wrong
        //$('#error').html(value + " is an incorrect input value");
        $('#error').slideDown();
      }
    }
  });
});

$('#submit_form').addEventListener('click', function (event) {

// Prevents form from submitting
             event.preventDefault();

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "submit_form.php",
       dataType: "json",
       data: $('#form_1').serialize(),
       success: function (json) {
        $('.message_center').html('');

        if(json['success']) {

         $('.message_center')
          .html('<div class="row">'+
            '   <div class="col-md-12">'+
            '     <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">'+
            '       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>'+
            '       <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i> Success!</h4>'+
            '       '+json['success']+''+
            '     </div>'+
            '   </div>'+
            ' </div> ');
       }

       if(json['error']) {

         var html='';
         $.each( json['error'], function( key, value ) {
          html += value+'<br>';
        });
        $('.message_center')
          .html('<div class="row">'+
            '   <div class="col-md-12">'+
            '     <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible">'+
            '       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>'+
            '       <h4><i class="icon fa fa-warning"></i> Error! There was a problem.</h4>'+
            '       '+html+''+
            '     </div>'+
            '   </div>'+
            ' </div> ');
       }

    }

   });
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks alex.I did the validation.I want to only know how to display the error messages automatically by styling the div tag in html using css.

Comment: You can add a style tag before the body where you can styling the div tag. I modified the code for give you an example. If i helped you, thanks to up vote or validate to inform others :)

Comment: Thank you very much alex..it almost fixed my problem..but here the div is declared inside the file, I wanted to know what can i do for the username and password that will be checked from the database.I mean how to give error message for wrong username and password .I would really be thankful if you can give me some guidance

Comment: If you want to stay on same page if validation fails, it is something like that you want :
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42104258/ajax-php-stay-on-same-page-if-validation-fails), but i can't test without your database (posgres, mysql, the tables, the columns, how you access it...). I added another snippet witch use ajax and php, but i can't make it return on the page because it is not my server. You have to try with your own page name : something.php an fill the ajax part for your server. My answer have no vote, don't forget to up vote or validate.

Comment: Thank you again alex...i will try to run it in my page and hopefully it will work..Thanks

Comment: I found the answer helpful and so I gave an upvote but its not showing since I am new to stackoverflow and my reputation level is less than 15